# X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile() on .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, x509certificate2

I am trying to use `X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile()` method in an ASP.NET Core application, but it seems like it's not supported for .NET Core.

Is there an alternative way of creating an `X509Certificate2` object from a cert/pfx file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public Certificate CreateFromCertFile()
{
    string cerFile = @"c:\cer.txt";
    string keyFile = @"c:\key.txt";

    var cert = new X509Certificate2(cerFile);
    cert.PrivateKey = CreateRSAFromFile(keyFile);

    return  cert;
}

private RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateRSAFromFile(string filename)
{
    byte[] pvk = null;
    using (var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        pvk = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(pvk, 0, pvk.Length);
    }

    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportCspBlob(pvk);

    return rsa;
}
```