# Create X509Certificate2 from PEM file in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate, private-key, pem

I want to create a X509Certificate2 object based on a PEM file. The problem is setting the PrivateKey property of X509Certificate2. I read [X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile() on .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845076/x509certificate2-createfromcertfile-on-net-core)
 and then used

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

rsa.ImportCspBlob(pvk);
```

Where `pvk` is the byte array of the private key (read from GetBytesFromPEM as shown here [how to get private key from PEM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file)), to set the private key, but then I get an

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException with message Bad Version of provider.

How can I properly set the PrivateKey of the X509Certificate2 based on the private key in the PEM file?

If I look at [Creating the X509Certificate2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162194/Certificates-to-DB-and-Back), they use

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = Crypto.DecodeRsaPrivateKey(keyBuffer);
 certificate.PrivateKey = prov;
```

which seems like a neat way to do this, but this does not work in .Net Core...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've just extracted the bytes from the Base64 encoding of the private key file you have a PKCS#1, PKCS#8, or encrypted PKCS#8 private key blob (depending on if it said "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY", "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" or "BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY").  `ImportCspBlob` wants a custom format for the data, and that's why it's complaining.

[Digital signature in c# without using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48905438/6535399) has an explanation of ways forward.  The easiest / most formulaic is to just make a PFX with the cert and key, and let the `X509Certificate2` constructor do its thing.

If you go the route of loading the key object directly then the way you would mate a private key with the certificate is to use one of the new [`CopyWithPrivateKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods.  This returns a new instance of `X509Certificate2` which knows about the private key.

The `PrivateKey` setter was "removed" from .NET Core because it has a lot of side effects on Windows that are hard to replicate on Linux and macOS, particularly if you retrieved the certificate out of an instance of X509Store.

---

This code is a combination of overly strict and overly accepting for real BER rules, but this should read validly encoded PKCS#8 files unless they included attributes.

```
private static readonly byte[] s_derIntegerZero = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };

private static readonly byte[] s_rsaAlgorithmId =
{
    0x30, 0x0D,
    0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
    0x05, 0x00,
};

private static int ReadLength(byte[] data, ref int offset)
{
    byte lengthOrLengthLength = data[offset++];

    if (lengthOrLengthLength < 0x80)
    {
        return lengthOrLengthLength;
    }

    int lengthLength = lengthOrLengthLength & 0x7F;
    int length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthLength; i++)
    {
        if (length > ushort.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This seems way too big.");
        }

        length <<= 8;
        length |= data[offset++];
    }

    return length;
}

private static byte[] ReadUnsignedInteger(byte[] data, ref int offset, int targetSize = 0)
{
    if (data[offset++] != 0x02)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encoding");
    }

    int length = ReadLength(data, ref offset);

    // Encoding rules say 0 is encoded as the one byte value 0x00.
    // Since we expect unsigned, throw if the high bit is set.
    if (length < 1 || data[offset] >= 0x80)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encoding");
    }

    byte[] ret;

    if (length == 1)
    {
        ret = new byte[length];
        ret[0] = data[offset++];
        return ret;
    }

    if (data[offset] == 0)
    {
        offset++;
        length--;
    }

    if (targetSize != 0)
    {
        if (length > targetSize)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad key parameters");
        }

        ret = new byte[targetSize];
    }
    else
    {
        ret = new byte[length];
    }

    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offset, ret, ret.Length - length, length);
    offset += length;
    return ret;
}

private static void EatFullPayloadTag(byte[] data, ref int offset, byte tagValue)
{
    if (data[offset++] != tagValue)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encoding");
    }

    int length = ReadLength(data, ref offset);

    if (data.Length - offset != length)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Data does not represent precisely one value");
    }
}

private static void EatMatch(byte[] data, ref int offset, byte[] toMatch)
{
    if (data.Length - offset > toMatch.Length)
    {
        if (data.Skip(offset).Take(toMatch.Length).SequenceEqual(toMatch))
        {
            offset += toMatch.Length;
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad data.");
}

private static RSA DecodeRSAPkcs8(byte[] pkcs8Bytes)
{
    int offset = 0;

    // PrivateKeyInfo SEQUENCE
    EatFullPayloadTag(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, 0x30);
    // PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo.version == 0
    EatMatch(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, s_derIntegerZero);
    // rsaEncryption AlgorithmIdentifier value
    EatMatch(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, s_rsaAlgorithmId);
    // PrivateKeyInfo.privateKey OCTET STRING
    EatFullPayloadTag(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, 0x04);
    // RSAPrivateKey SEQUENCE
    EatFullPayloadTag(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, 0x30);
    // RSAPrivateKey.version == 0
    EatMatch(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, s_derIntegerZero);

    RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
    rsaParameters.Modulus = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset);
    rsaParameters.Exponent = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset);
    rsaParameters.D = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, rsaParameters.Modulus.Length);
    int halfModulus = (rsaParameters.Modulus.Length + 1) / 2;
    rsaParameters.P = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, halfModulus);
    rsaParameters.Q = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, halfModulus);
    rsaParameters.DP = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, halfModulus);
    rsaParameters.DQ = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, halfModulus);
    rsaParameters.InverseQ = ReadUnsignedInteger(pkcs8Bytes, ref offset, halfModulus);

    if (offset != pkcs8Bytes.Length)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Something didn't add up");
    }

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
    return rsa;
}
```

Comment: The reason for why I am using PEM format is that the certificate is stored as a secret in Kubernetes. Would it be possible somehow to read the certificate as a string, convert the content to PFX format - and then use this as input to X509Certificate2's constructor?

Comment: Update: So, when I try:
using (CngKey key = CngKey.Import(p8bytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob))
                {
                    var rsaCng= new RSACng(key);
                    X509Certificate2 certWithPrivateKey = 
                   certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaCng);
                },
the RSACng object is fine, but when CopyWithPrivateKey is called, I get an exception stating 'The requested operation is not supported'.. can you see any obvious mistakes there? @bartonjs

Comment: Another comment here is that I am running the application in a Docker container in Kubernetes, so then CngKey won't work anyway?

Comment: @heydy Ah, since CngKey.Import doesn't let you name the key it can't bind it without doing a different export/import, but the key isn't exportable (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647314/6535399).  But, you are correct, CngKey only works on Windows.

Comment: @heydy Apparently I felt inspired today, and made a lightweight PKCS8 reader.  Enjoy.

Comment: For decoding the parameters, see also : https://github.com/StefH/OpenSSL-X509Certificate2-Provider

Answer (score 11):

Using .NET 5.0 we finally have a nice way of doing this.

The X509Certificate2 class provides two static methods `X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem` and `X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile`. So if you have the file path then can call:

```
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(filePath);
```

If creating the certificate without the file then can pass in `ReadOnlySpan<char>` for the certificate thumbprint and key. There are also `X509Certificate2.CreateFromEncryptedPem` and `X509Certificate2.CreateFromEncryptedPemFile` if the contents is encrypted.

More info can be found in the official API docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompemfile?view=net-5.0

Comment: When I use this I get the following error : "The TLS client credential's certificate does not have a private key information property attached to it. This most often occurs when a certificate is backed up incorrectly and then later restored. This message can also indicate a certificate enrollment failure." Would you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: .NET core 3.1 doesn't support that method.

Comment: Don't know why this is being upvoted. Neither of these methods deserializes the private key from the file.